# Ii need to get the remainder while dividing from 5 but I don't want to use modulus airthematic operator or a divider in verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I want to work with residue number system and make an ALU based on residue number system. So frequently I need to calculate the remainder and using modulo operator is not helping as it is not synthesizable.

Comment: What is the range of numbers you want to divide by 5?

Comment: You can implement a divider (and thus modulo operation) by writing a divider state-machine. If this goes in an FPGA: some vendors offer a divider block as IP. Others, I have been told, DO allow the divider operator in their latest SW revision. (p.s. You did not actually ask a question and "I" should be a capital)

Answer (score 2):

5 is a bit of an unhelpful number when it comes to binary arithmetic.
Fortunately however, it is a nice factor of 15.

15 is known as a Mersenne number - that is a number which is one less than a power of two (15 = 2<sup>4</sup>-1). One nice property of Mersenne numbers is that you can perform modulo in binary without using any division.

The following code should work for numbers up to 32bit:

```
module modulo5(
    input  [31:0] numIn,
    output [ 2:0] result
);
    wire [16:0] partOne   =   numIn[31:16] +         numIn[15:0];
    wire [ 9:0] partTwo   = partOne[16: 8] + {1'b0,partOne[ 7:0]};
    wire [ 5:0] partThree = partTwo[ 9: 4] + {1'b0,partTwo[ 3:0]};
    
    //Final step is to convert into modulo 5.
    //Because the result is limited in size, we can find this by a simple lookup table.
    //This should optimise into a single 6-bit LUT for each of the three output bits.
    
    reg [2:0] partFour [63:0];
    integer i;
    initial begin
        for (i = 0; i < 63; i = i + 1) begin
            partFour[i] = i % 5;
        end
    end
    
    //And the result
    assign result = partFour[partThree];
endmodyle
```

The final section is a simple lookup table. As the input was reduced to only 6-bit, that stage can be realised with three 6-bit LUTs so is actually incredibly efficient.

If your input was only up to 10-bit, you could skip parts one and two.
For inputs up to 17-bit you can skip part one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a state machine that repeatedly subtracts 5 from the value in question, stopping when the result is less than 5. Without more information from you that's the most generic suggestion I can make.